# #1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '' without foreign key

Tags: mysql

I got this error on select statement in MySQL.

First one without error :

```
select '2018-09-01' as rdate,
       model,
       part_no,
       sum(part_cost*count(*))
from table1
left join table2 on table1.part_no = table2.part_no
where issue > '2018-09-01'
and issue_date <= '2018-09-30'
group by model, table1.part_no
```

2nd cause

> 1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '' (it is blank)
>   select '2018-09-01' as rdate, model, part_no, sum(part_cost*count(*)) from table1 left join table2 on table1.part_no = table2.part_no where  issue_date<='2018-09-30' group by model, table1.part_no

`table1` have index on `model`,`part_no` and `table1` have index on `part_no`.

I just remove `issue > '2018-09-01'`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Will the query result include many more rows when you remove the filter on `issue`? Could you perhaps run out of disk space if some temp table gets to large?

Comment: Maybe you should run [myisamchk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisamchk.html) to verify the dB is ok.

Comment: There is no insert or update here so you are not writing, did you post the full query?

Comment: Actually I insert the select result into another table but even the select clause cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I simplify my query, actually I also use ' upper (model) as model' then try with model only, and it works. I just wonder why the error message doesn't pinpoint the cause of error. Of cause the real cause of error is still a mystery.